# Angular js get div element issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get a div element value by ng-click but it comes an alert `undefined`.
my html is

```
<div ng-model='myName'>this is my name</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Show Name" ng-click="showName()"/>
```

script is

```
$scope.showName = function(){
        var nameOne = $scope.myName;
        alert(nameOne);
    }
```

How to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: You can't use ng-model with div element: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: Ok thanks. then how to get div element if I use `<div class='myName'>this is my name</div>`. In jquery it is simple `$('.myName').text()`.

Comment: You should never use jquery inside your controller. With you need some logic related to View, create a directive.

Comment: @try_simple_code The point is. In a general way if this is in a div you shouldn't need to get the value. div are kind of read-only elements. Why do you need to get the content of this div ?

Comment: yes, I dont try to use jquery inside angular.  @Okazari I want this div element because I want to append it other div for some reason.

Comment: @try_simple_code Then, how do you generate the content of this div ?

Answer (score 2):

ngModel directive can't be used with plain div (unless the element is a custom form control), see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

```
<div ng-init="myName = 'this is my name'">{{ myName }}</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Show Name" ng-click="showName()"/>
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/16B8o0UVCm7HG02cEAxy?p=preview)

Edit: using `ngInit` outside of `ngRepeat` is considered a [bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), initialize scope vars in the controller

```
$scope.myName = 'this is my name';
$scope.showName = function() {
    alert($scope.myName);
}
```

Comment: ngModel can be used in any element, also ngInit should not be used for initialising scope variables under normal circumstances, that's what the controller is for.

Comment: @Wawy "ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using", so it CAN be used, but will do nothing. ngInit was shown for the sake of example, but I would agree with you that myName should be initialized int the controller

Comment: @Wawy ng-model "should" be use on input (& co) unless you don't provide a custom directive configuring the ng-model controller.

Comment: @sbedulin you can use ngModel in any element as it is used when creating custom form controls as (datepickers, custom dropboxes, etc..) If you agree about the ngInit then you shouldn't answer people that is learning angularjs with bad practises...

Comment: Cmon, people should be aware of bad practices! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>{{myName}}</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Show Name" ng-click="showName()"/>
```

script is

```
$scope.showName = function(){
        var nameOne = $scope.myName;
        alert(nameOne);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually ng-model should be use on inputs.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myName">
```

This Will create a $scope.myName var and bind it to the input content.

If you intitialize the myName in your javascript and want it to be displayed in this div you should use this syntax :

JS

```
$scope.myName = "Ben";
```

HTML

```
<div>This is my name : {{myName}}</div>
```

In both case your button click will not show undefined unless you didn't initialize it before the click (on the 2nd exemple).

Hope it helped.